# Yii routes and creation of URLs with multiple parameters

Tags: php, url, yii, routes

I would like to get the URL as follow:

> `http://domain.com/post/1/some-titles-here`

But I'm getting:

> `http://domain.com/post/1?title=some-titles-here`

I am using this config:

```
'urlFormat' => 'path',
...
//'post/<id:\d+>/<title>' => 'post/view/', 
'post/<id:\d+>/<title:\w+>' => 'post/view/',
'post/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view/',
...
```

Then to get the URL I am executing:

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('post/view', array('id' => $this->id,'title' => $this->title));
```

im following the third rule here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters

Comment: Hey, I think it's matching this:
    `post/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view/`

Can you try:
    `post/<id:\d+>/*' => 'post/view/`,

Comment: hi Jeroes, same output.

Comment: im following the third rule on this doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters

Comment: You may have another rule that matches first. Can you show all your rules before the ones you posted?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you're using to match the title is incorrect: `<title:\w+>` will only match single words but your title has hyphens as well.

Tuan is correct; it's matching the next rule. That's because the URL manager works its way down the rules until it finds one that matches.

Use this rule instead:

```
'post/<id:\d+>/<title:([A-Za-z0-9-]+)>' => 'post/view/',
```

That will match titles with letters, numbers, and hyphens.

Comment: Simply leave away the regular expression for `title`. This will match everything that is not a `/`. Also better remove the trailing `/` after your route: `'post/<id:\d+>/<title>' => 'post/view'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code that work for me:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules'=>array(
         '' => 'site/index',
         'article/<id:\d+>/<alias:[-\w]+>' => 'article/view',
         'article/cat/<id:\d+>-<alias:[-\w]+>' => 'category/view',
```

Result urls:

- http://wowjp.black.dragon/article/2/test-zagolovka
- http://wowjp.black.dragon/article/cat/3-345435